# Regex for tokenize in xQuery

Tags: regex, xpath, xquery, tokenize

using xPath i'm getting a text like this:

> Sed id felis mi; Nam porta lacinia sapien vestibulum egestas; Praesent nec nisl purus, eget mollis metus. Fusce euismod ante id tellus tincidunt dignissim ornare magna blandit. Nunc id risus quam.

I want to split it into two variables :

var1 = text from the beginning till the 1st dot => if this part contains more than 10 words (separated by a blank space) and contains a semicolon ';', then it will take text from the beginning till the 1st semicolon.

var2 = the right part of the text.

I started with this code, but it doesn't give me what I want (I didn't treated the 10 words condition yet):

```
let $left := data(tokenize($doc//div/blockquote/p/text(), '^(.*?)[;|.](.*?)$')[1])
let $right := data(tokenize($doc//div/blockquote/p/text(), '^(.*?)[;|.](.*?)$')[2])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
for $p in doc('file:///c:/test.xml')//div/blockquote/p/text()
    return 
        if (count(tokenize(tokenize($p,'[.]')[1],'\s+')) gt 10) then
            (tokenize($p,'[.]')[1])
        else
            (tokenize($p,';')[1])
```

**For reference see [fn:tokenize](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize).**

Comment: shouldn't both return values change places?

Comment: Your code works perfectly (after little modification for my needs). Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4):

Can be done even without using `tokenize()` or any RegEx:

```
   for $s in 'Sed id felis mi; Nam porta lacinia sapien vestibulum egestas; Praesent nec nisl purus, eget mollis metus. Fusce euismod ante id tellus tincidunt dignissim ornare magna blandit. Nunc id risus quam.',
       $vBeforeDot in substring-before($s, '.'),
       $vBeforeSemiC in substring-before($s, ';')
      return
         ($vBeforeDot
                       [string-length(normalize-space(.))
                       - string-length(translate(normalize-space(.), ' ', ''))
                       le 9
                       ],
        $vBeforeSemiC
        )[1]
```

Comment: +1, What a splendid XPath 1.0 solution. Wish I could give more votes on this.